# Shopify Get Product by ID

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

Get the product by ID shopify. This one is giving first items(Like upto 300), but when I try to get last ones(Like 400+) it will not return it. Anyway to overcome this?

```
{% paginate collections.all.products by 1000 %}
  {% for product in collections.all.products %}
    {% if product.id == product_test_id%}
      {% assign shopifyProduct = product %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

Comment: Use Shopify product slug to get the particular product, with ID you can't able to get it.

Comment: Check [all_products](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/objects#all_products) global object for more information.

Comment: You can get all the data from a product in Shopify by going to the product in the admin and adding .xml to the end of the url.

Comment: @pete I want to use this on theme file.

Comment: @Onkar this is not working.

Comment: what you tried, can you please share the code that you tried.